# How can you access the real time clock from a kernel module?

Tags: c, interface, linux-kernel, header-files

I am new to linux kernel modules and want to create a kernel module that interacts with the proc file system.

My Idea is to create a file in /proc that has a read that returns the real-time clocks hours, minutes and seconds.

However I am not sure how to use the linux/rtc.h interface to get whats required or if thats even the place I should be looking to try and access the real time clock hardware.

Any ideas on where to start looking to complete this would be greatly appreciated cause I am completely stuck right now.

Comment: Try finding out what the `gettimeofday(2)` system call does.

Comment: gettimeofday(2) is good for checking what linux is providing as the time. But the only place I would use gettimeofday(2) would be to compare my driver managed time to linux's.

Comment: Yes of course.  What I'm suggesting is that you read the source code for `gettimeofday` to see which internal kernel functions it uses to get the time.  Those will probably be the same functions you want.

Comment: /proc/driver/rtc already exists and is deprecated